# How to limit number of rows to run a for loop to copy values to another column using Google sheets script?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to past a hostel booking information about guests to a database. I want to copy guests information and feed a form that will save reservation information to the database.

It can be from one up to nine guests, so I am using `*` on the row before the first guest and `**` after the last one.

Here is the code:

```
function dadosColadosDaAgenda() {

  var myGoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var testeSheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("TesteSheet");
  var valoresImportados = testeSheet.getRange("G1:G22").getValues();
    
  for (var i = 0; i < 29; i++) {

    var rowValue = valoresImportados[i];

    //Get Cel Phone   
    if (rowValue?.toString().startsWith("Cel: ")){
      var telefone =rowValue.toString().replace("Cel: ","");
      testeSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(telefone);
    }
   
    //Get ID
    if (rowValue?.toString().startsWith("ID")){
      var idReserva= rowValue.toString().replace("ID: ","");
      testeSheet.getRange("B1").setValue(idReserva);
    }

    //Get guests
    
    if (rowValue == "*") {
      var startHospedes = testeSheet.getRange([i],7).getRow()+1;      
      Logger.log(startHospedes);
    }

    if (rowValue == "**") {

      var endHospedes= testeSheet.getRange([i],7).getRow()+1;
     // if I remove this +1, the next FOR loop won't run, but the way it is it returns ** as the last guest

      var nH= endHospedes-startHospedes-1;
      Logger.log(endHospedes);
      Logger.log(nH);

      testeSheet.getRange(15,2).setValue(nH); //number of guests
    }
      
    if (i > startHospedes + 1 && i < endHospedes) {
    //when I type the value I got at Logger.log(endHospedes) it works fine,
    //but it won't work if I use &&i<endHospedes when the var endHospedes doesn't have +1 at the end
      
      Logger.log(rowValue);

      for (var j=3;j<12;j++) {
          
        var valoresJ = valoresImportados[startHospedes++];         
        testeSheet.getRange(j,2).setValue(valoresJ);
        }
    }     
  }   
}
```

I will need to do the same to get car's licence plate. All the values will be pasted on column G and then organized and move to column B.

I am a novice at javascript, and would appreciate very much any help to understand what I am doing wrong. Cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and add a language tag. The post mentions "java" but this looks more like javascript.

Comment: Done. Hope I did it right. Cheers